# Rotating webbrowser from current orientation is stretching(zooming) the webbrowser contents Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, browser, windows-phone-8.1

I have a webbrowser which is in portrait mode. I am loading the webbrowser using

```
this.webBrowserControl.Source = new Uri("http://google.com");
```

When the content is loaded the view looks like this[image]

there is rotate button provided, so if user is in portrait mode and user presses rotate button then I am rotating the webview using transform and setting its height and width so that it can occupy the whole screen

```
pageWidth = 480;
pageHeight = 800;
RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform();
transform.Angle = 90;
this.webbrowser.RenderTransform = transform;
webbrowser.Width = pageHeight;
webbrowser.Height = pageWidth;
```

The webbrowser is rotated but the contents looks like zoomed or stretched, it lo[image]oks like this

Any idea how not to zoom the content??

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Change Zoom percentage:

```
// figure out the ratio you want to reduce by
string zoom_js = "document.body.style.zoom=\"50%\";";

try
{
    this.myBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    this.myBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", zoom_js);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

---

It is not zooming anything.  It just that you are rotating it then stretching (resizing) the container.

Given your resolution, you have to have keep the aspect ratio if you don't want any stretching to be done.

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="myBrowser" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="480" Width="480" Margin="0" Padding="0">
        <phone:WebBrowser.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="90"/>
        </phone:WebBrowser.RenderTransform>
    </phone:WebBrowser>
</Border>
```

Now that won't be stretched but it also not cover the entire screen.  Now, imagine stretching the container like you did.  The result will be your image you posted.

Comment: But the requirement is, to cover the entire screen. Any suggestions??

Comment: @nucleons You can't resize an image larger without running into those artifacts.  You can reduce the artifacts by using another interpolation method, but it probably would too long to put as a SO answer.  Your best bet is to trick the `WebBrowser` to render if it was in Landscape mode, then you can rotate it and it will be the ratio that you want.

Comment: So whether i need to rotate the PhoneApplicationPage to landscape?? Because I am keeping the webbrowser in a popup. Or how can I render WebBrowser in Landscape??

Comment: @nucleons added a bit more info on how to change zoom dynamically, but I still think it's a stretching issue.  Maybe you can use the zoom-out to fake the effect you wish to achieve.